# Apache RewriteEngine On causes 403 error

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos6

I have a Linux box running Centos 6.6 with Apaches 2.2.x
For some unknown reason, turning on the rewrite engine causes a 403 error (this happens whether I add a rewrite rule or not).

I have spent hours researching this and have made changes to my config in accordance with advice I have found in many places, but still got nowhere.

Currently in my .htaccess I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
</IfModule>
```

In the directives for the virtual host, I have this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.uk  
<Directory /var/www/html/example.uk>  
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ServerName example.uk  
ServerAlias www.example.uk
```

(This seems to work in a Debian box, but not for my Centos machine.)

In my httpd.conf I have changed

> AllowOverride None

to

> AllowOverride All

my httpd.conf also contains
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Error log says:

> Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/html/example.uk

Now, I have previously added **SymLinksIfOwnerMatch** to the directives, but it didn't solve the problem.

I followed [this](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache/) and all seemed to go as it should.

Comment: what page are you getting the 403? Do you have an index file in that location?

Comment: @PanamaJack the root. There is an index.php there, which displays fine if I comment out RewriteEngine On

Comment: check your apache log file and see what error it's saying why you're getting 403

Comment: @PanamaJack I have added it to the question

Comment: Do you have access to your logs? if so, check them and put logs for a single request here!

Comment: @undone `Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/html/example.uk/`

Comment: Did you try to enable FollowSymLinks but disable SymLinksIfOwnerMatch?

Comment: @Capsule: yes. Didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

This happens when Apache doesn't have execute rights for

```
/var
/var/www
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/example.uk
```

Run:

```
chmod o+x /var /var/www /var/www/html /var/www/html/example.uk
```

Comment: I tried this and restarted apache. Still didn't work.

Comment: No, still have the problem.

Comment: This actually helped me. Apache was the owner, but didn't have execution rights. chmod to /var/www/html 755 did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Since apache version >= 2.4 directive

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

leads to a global 403, to ensure this if you check you're apache's log :

> [Tue May 05 11:54:32.471679 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 9497] [client 127.0.0.1:35908] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /path/to/web/

Comment Directive `Order` and add `Require all granted` like bellow:

```
 Require all granted
 #Order allow,deny
 #allow from all
```

Hope this help.

**Edit :**

[explanation from apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html#page-header)
This behaviour is provided by new module `mod_authz_host`

For list of restriction available (ip, host, etc) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Comment: Thanks, but that resulted in a 500 error. I think I will just have to forget about using .htaccess and use PHP instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove this line from htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

You already have it in the apache vhost file. Also if you should add a rule if you're going to turn on mod_rewrite or there is no point to turning it on.

Comment: Did you add a rewriterule?

Comment: added `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.uk/$1 [R,L]` still got 403 error

Comment: When you added this to the vhost file did your restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I restarted apache

Comment: Try changing `Indexes` to `-Indexes` in the vhost and restart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76080/discussion-between-jez-d-and-panama-jack).

Comment: The chat rooms doesn't seem to be displaying right. Dude something else then is messed up with the configuration. Check the permissions on the htaccess file make sure it's 644. Or try and redo your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with Apache 2.4 is caused by `Options -FollowSymlinks` which will also throw a 403 error and generate the following log:

> AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off,
>   so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar
>   ability to circumvent directory restrictions

This was not the case in the original post, but if it comes up you would need to re-enable FollowSymLinks using this line:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. To add clarity, & to round out your post as a complete answer, may I suggest adding the exact code needed to re-enable `FollowSymLinks`. This way a user not as familiar with this technology could apply your suggestion without first being  required to do additional research to learn how. Completely self-contained answers are more useful, & more likely to be upvoted. Simply adding 1 line of code to the end of your post would be an excellent addition. If this is something people might want to read more about, adding a source link, if you have one, is always welcomed.